# error: conflicting declaration using universal references

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I wanted to implement universal *reverse* function from the [article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/02/11/reverse-for-loops-in-cpp/) and it works for rvalue. But doesn't with lvalue.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class Reverse
{
    T iterable_;  
public:
    explicit Reverse(T&& iterable) : iterable_(std::forward<T>(iterable)){}

    auto begin() { return std::rbegin(iterable_); }
    auto end() { return std::rend(iterable_); }
};

std::vector<int> CreateVector()
{
    return {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};   // line 23

    for(const auto& i : Reverse(CreateVector()))
        std::cout << i << " "; 
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Reverse(v);                          // line 29
    // for(const auto& i : Reverse(v))
    //   std::cout << i << " "; 

    return 0;    
}
```

I got an error for lvalue:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:13: error: conflicting declaration 'Reverse<...auto...> v'
   29 |     Reverse(v);
      |             ^
main.cpp:23:22: note: previous declaration as 'std::vector<int> v'
   23 |     std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
      |
```

Can you please show me a direction to the right solution?

Comment: The `T&&` in the constructor are not forwarding references but r-value references to `T` that is a fixed type in the class. You have to template the constructor itself.

Comment: @n314159 thank you, I forgot about templating calling function.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't use universal/forwarding reference, you just use plain R-value reference.

You want syntax `template<class T> F(T&&)` (constructor must be template function):

```
template<class F>
explicit Reverse(F&& iterable) : iterable_(std::forward<T>(iterable)){}
```

If you use C++17 or later, you can add deduction guide:

```
template<class T>
Reverse(T&&) -> Reverse<T>;
```

by adding above, you don't have to specify explicitly template parameter of `Reverse` class when instatiating its objects. Without CTAD you need to write: `Reverse<decltype(v)>(..)` to handle R-values, or `Reverse<decltype((v))>` for L-values (most inner parentheses are required to get L-value reference to container).

And if you want to create temporary `Reverse` taking `v` as argument, just write:

```
Reverse{v};
```

(now for `Reverse(v)` you do redeclaration of `v` variable) or as named instance:

```
Reverse withLvalue(v);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/iKr28T)

Comment: Thank you for _deduction guide_, now I understand how and where to use it :)

Comment: I think, you need `std::forward<F>` and not `std::forward<T>`. Pre-C++17 the normal do get around the problem of specifying `T` would be to add a factory function `template<class T> Reverse<T> make_reverse(T&& t) { return Reverse<T>{std::forward<T>(t);};}`

Answer (score 0):

If you would enable warnings, you would get a very important clue to that error:

```
warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of 'v' [-Wparentheses]
   46 |     Reverse(v)
```

From compiler perspective, `v` is name of the object (parantheses are ignored). Since object called `v` already exists, you must choose different name.

**Prefer uniform initialization whenever possible.** It will not leave space for ambiguity.

```
Reverse{v};
```

---

The next problem you will encounter is that you are trying to bind l-value (vector `v`) to r-value reference in `Reference` constructor. You have to move the vector into this object if you want to keep that constructor.

```
Reverse{std::move(v)};
```

Note that `v` is left `empty()` after this operation. The data is only held by `iterable_` now.

---

Lastly, the `Reverse` object is a temporary, that is discarded immediately after construction. You probably want to give it some name to use it in the loop later (or construct temporary in-place like you did in your first loop).

```
Reverse myReverse {std::move(v)};
for(const auto& i : myReverse )
   std::cout << i << " "; 
//or
for(const auto& i : Reverse{std::move(v)} )
   std::cout << i << " ";
```